# Issue: Data synchronization state of availability database is not healthy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, high-availability

I have a sqlserver 2017 cluster (sql server 14.0.3026.27) with two secondary nodes set with Availability Mode = Synchronous commit. The server has 8 databases that are replicated on the secondary nodes. The network speed between nodes is very high - when I transfer big files I get speeds of over 200MB per second.

I restored the databases from a sql server 2008 on the primary node and I tried to replicate them to the secondary nodes using the process where I remove them from the Availability Database on the primary, I delete them from the secondary nodes and I add them back to the Availability Databases on the primary following that "Add Database..."  dialog (I selected Automatic Seeding) . It's a hit and miss process. Some of the databases were not synchronized, so I had to repeat the process over and over until I got them all synchronized. At least in the past. Now I am stuck with one database that stubbornly refuses to synchronize.

When I go to the Availability Dashboard, it shows two warnings besides the database that has the Synchronization State = Not Synchronizing:

> Data synchronization state of availability database is not healthy.
>
> The data synchronization state of this availability database is
>   unhealthy. On an asynchronous-commit availability replica, every
>   availability database should be in the SYNCHRONIZING state. On a
>   synchronous-commit replica, every availability database should be in
>   the SYNCHRONIZED state.

and

> Secondary database is not joined.
>
> This secondary database is not joined to the availability group. The
>   configuration of this secondary database is incomplete. For
>   information about how to join a secondary database to an availability
>   group, see SQL Server Books Online.

I looked in the logs on the primary and secondary nodes there is nothing relevant there.

I found these article:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3380.sql-server-data-synchronization-state-of-some-availability-database-is-not-healthy.aspx

But they don't have any useful suggestions.

At this point, the only thing that works is repeating the process multiple times and eventually all the databases are synchronized.

Do you have any suggestions on how to make this process predictable? Upgrade to latest sql server 2017 patch? Upgrade to sql server 2019?

While I was writing this post, I went to this page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4047329/sql-server-2017-build-versions. We are definitely behind with the releases. We are on CU7 and the latest release is CU20. Our cluster has been configured by another group and I don't know if they vetted the latest patches.
Going through the list of patches I found this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4538275/fix-database-initialization-may-fail-by-using-automatic-seeding-in-sql.

This looks like the problem I am experiencing. I used Automatic Seeding for replication.

I am going to look into upgrading to the latest CU and I will come back to the thread.

Comment: Have you try the backup restore instead of the auto seeding ?

Comment: Yes, the backup restore worked.

Comment: So it "fixed" your problem ?

Comment: Yes and no. I was able to synchronize all databases, however, in log run at least in CU7, Automatic Seeding is not reliable. I haven't installed CU20 yet but I will come back to the thread after I do it with an update. I guess for now I have to stick to synchronization via backups.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have found automatic seeding to be unreliable as well, particularly when multiple databases are added at one time, or when there are multiple secondaries.

Comment: In my case I had two secondaries. And yes, I added multiple databases, one was successfully synchronized on both, another database just on one of the secondaries. What version do you use? I just installed CU20. I will keep an eye on it - right now I don't have any changes to make. I will come back to this thread to write about my experience.